# What math institutes offer research in pairs/research in teams?

Tags: soft-question, big-list, career

Some math institutes offer programs in which a small number of researchers are enabled to meet at the institute for a week or more.  A list seemed as if it could be useful.

Answer (score 24):

As far as I know, the "Research in Pairs" program appeared first and still exists in the Mathematisches Forschungsinstitut Oberwolfach. See http://www.mfo.de/

As for the list of such possibilities, one can look through the list of all institutes of this kind:
http://www.math.psu.edu/MathLists/institutes.php

Comment: Another list of institutes is at http://www.fields.utoronto.ca/aboutus/IMSI.html (copied from an answer to a different question on MathOverflow by Brian Borchers); some institutes appear on one list, some on the other, some on both, and some on neither.  I expect the list of institutes that I am looking for is quite a bit shorter.  

Comment: Oberwolfach recommends applying about six months in advance; a visit can run from two weeks to three months.

Comment: The psu link no longer seems to work. Do you know of an updated link?

Answer (score 16):

[BIRS](https://www.birs.ca/programs/general-program-descriptions) in Banff, Alberta, Canada, offers "research in teams" (2-4 people, 1-2 weeks) and "focussed research groups" (up to eight researchers, 1-2 weeks).

Comment: According to their website, the "preferred" time to apply (for research in pairs in 2013) is September 30, 2011.  However, applications are accepted until four months prior to the desired time.  

Answer (score 15):

In France:

a. Institut Henri Poincaré (Paris)

'Research in Paris' (yes, Paris not pairs)

http://www.ihp.fr/en  (under "Activities" one will find "Research in Paris")

b. CIRM (Marseille/Luminy)

'Recherche en binôme' / Research in pairs

http://www.cirm-math.com/ (under "Scientific"  one will find "research in pairs")

Comment: I've also had occasion in the past to play with "Paris --> Pairs" :-)

Comment: Is 'Recherche en binôme' really 'research in binomial'?

Comment: @FanZheng in French "binôme" is used in the mathematical sense, but also generally for designating a group of two. I suppose the double-meaning is what made them chose that word.

Answer (score 14):

The Hausdorff Institute in Bonn (http://www.hausdorff-research-institute.uni-bonn.de/index) offer research in small groups of size at least 3.

Answer (score 13):

The American Institute of Mathematics in San Jose has a nice program for collaborations:

http://aimath.org/research/squares.html

Comment: Dead link, and San Jose is no longer the place :)

Answer (score 13):

This is a little bit off the beaten path, and definitely not for all personalities, but the high school summer program Canada/USA Mathcamp has a Research in Pairs program ([details here](http://www.mathcamp.org/gettoknowmathcamp/academics/researchinpairs.php)) for which we're happy to receive unsolicited applications.  In brief: collaborators visit the program, teach 1 hr/day (on whatever they'd like) to very very bright high school students, and spend the rest of their time on their research program.

Answer (score 10):

As of today, an additional option exists at EPFL:

https://bernoulli.epfl.ch/bernoulliBrainstorm

Comment: This one is no longer around, right?

Answer (score 7):

RIMS Kyoto says (in Japanese) they host at least two for 1-2 weeks collaboration http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/ja/research-01.html

Answer (score 7):

There is also a Research in Pairs program at the ICMAT, in Madrid. From the [institute page](http://www.icmat.es/severo-ochoa/Activities/ICMat_ResearchInPairs),

*Research in pairs Programme aims at small groups of 2-4 researchers from different places working together on a specific project for a short period of time.*

Comment: The site is dead; is the program still around?

Comment: It was around seven years ago, but it is gone now. There are some other opportunities to visit ICMAT, but you can fish them around in their page.

Answer (score 5):

The Mittag-Leffler institute near Stockholm has another RIP (this time it stands for "Research in peace") programme.

Comment: Is this still around? I find nothing about it on their website.

Answer (score 5):

This program is fairly new, but I can say from experience that it's a beautiful facility and great working environment.

Collaborate@ICERM

https://icerm.brown.edu/collaborate/

Collaborate@ICERM offers teams of 3-6 researchers the opportunity to spend five days at the institute during the summer (May-August) or in the month of January. The team research project should have a computational or experimental component.

Answer (score 5):

The Centro di Ricerca Matematica Ennio De Giorgi at the Scuola Normale Superiore of Pisa usually has a program of research in pairs: 
http://crm.sns.it/visit/pairs.html

Answer (score 4):

The [International Centre for Mathematical Sciences](http://www.icms.org.uk) (ICMS) in Edinburgh (Scotland) offers [Research in Groups](http://www.icms.org.uk/proposals/rigs).  This institute is associated to the University of Edinburgh and Heriot-Watt University.

There’s more information on the linked page, but the gist of it is this:

- 2-4 researchers wishing to organise a short, intensive period of research in Edinburgh
- at least one researcher must be based in the UK
- not all researchers should be from the same university, with a maximum of two researchers from any one university

There are three deadlines for submitting a Research-in-Groups proposal each year: 30 April, 30 August and 30 December.

Answer (score 3):

The CIRM in Trento (Italy) has a Research in pairs program (for 2-3 people, 1-6 weeks):

http://cirm.fbk.eu/research-pairs

Answer (score 3):

The Erwin Schrodinger Institute in Vienna has a research in teams program:
https://www.esi.ac.at/activities/research-in-teams-short

Unlike some other programs, this supports visits of 1 - 4 months.

Comment: More up-to-date link (although not exactly full of information): https://www.esi.ac.at/events/research-in-teams/info